# flutter, vscode) how to browse widget's named argument automatically?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

In some people's viscose environment, when they click(or select) widget. It shows widget's named argument automatically(like attached picture). How can I do that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7OWZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with: CTRL + Space

You can change it under: Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Trigger Suggest.